# joomla countdown-module with programmable events

Tags: events, joomla, module, countdown

I wish to integrate a countdown-timer-module on a Joomla3.4-Page.
But the problem is, that in the extensions I found you can only edit the date for the next event.
My customer needs to type in a list of all events in the whole year so that he doesn't have to edit the event-date after every event.
It would be great if someone can suggest me a joomla-extension where I can program a list of following events in.
If the extension would support an flexible text for every event that would be ideal!

Thanks for your response,
Lukas

Comment: There are events components that can host unlimited events. I don't know if any of these have a countdown module - but generally it won't be hard to develop it. However your question might fit better in the [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), as this current site is for programming questions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Ok, I will take a look on the events components. Sorry, next time I will use the joomla-stack-exchange.